# Windows Form application. Difference between making an installer or keep it as an executable

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm developing an app for Windows desktop with c# and sql in visual studio 2019. I have seen that you can make an installer for your project, but I'm using the ".exe" of the Release folder with no problems.

What's the difference or advantages of each option?

I have not found any posts on this topic.

Comment: `but I'm using the ".exe" of the Release folder with no problems.` Have you tried running that same EXE on another PC that lacks Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project will use one .Net platform (.Net Frameword vX.x or .Net Core) and you can have references to OTHER DLL's.
If you only copy the .exe to another computer it will only work if you have the same .Net plaform installed and the OTHER DLL's are in the GAC.
If you distribute as installer it will try to collect and depencies and install them in the new computer.
All Windows 10 PC's have .Net Framework v4.5 pre-installed, so if you use that one and you .exe doens't reference nothing outside that world, it should work.

By experience, you should always use an installer.